# create main script to use PyQt4 windows with other objects

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt4

I am trying to learn how to use python and pyQt. 
I have done a window with Qtcreator then I used pyuic4, I have also created a class called `Ruban` I would like to use it with my window interface. In my window I have a button called `nouveauRuban`. I would like to create an object from my class `Ruban` when this button is clicked.

I know my code is wrong, the problem may be at the initial part of mainTN, on the `__init__` ?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from Ruban import Ruban

class mainTM(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None): #, parent=None ??
        super (mainTM, self).__init__(self, parent) #(parent) ??
        self.createWidgets()
        self.nouveauRuban.connect(nouveauRuban, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.nvRuban)

    def nvRuban(self):
        self.ruban=Ruban()
        self.ruban.info_ruban()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__== "__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp=mainTM()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a re-write of your script which should fix all the problems:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from Ruban import Ruban

class mainTM(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainTM, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.nouveauRuban.clicked.connect(self.nvRuban)

    def nvRuban(self):
        self.ruban = Ruban()
        self.ruban.info_ruban()

if __name__== '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = mainTM()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're connecting a signal to a slot, you need to define that slot using a decorator:

```python
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def nvRuban(self):
    self.ruban=Ruban()
    self.ruban.info_ruban()
```

Then connect it:

```python
self.nouveauRuban.clicked.connect(nvRuban)
```

Comment: The decorator will make no difference at all. It's the connection that was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It doesn't work yet, because of the __init__ () of the MainTM, there is something wrong...